# CryptoJS AES Decryption Not Giving original ZIP/EPUB file in react native

Tags: encryption, react-native, aes, cryptojs, react-native-fetch-blob

I am using CryptoJS to encrypt my `epub (or zip)` file and decrypt it. I am using `react native` to create the app. But I don't know why the decrypted file is not the original epub file. The error while opening the decrypted epub file is: `Error in opening zip file.` And I am using `react-native-fetch-blob` for file reading and writing.

Here is my code:

## Encryption

```
  encrypt() {

    // ENCRYPTION

    RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile(`${RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DownloadDir}/startup.epub`, 'base64')
    .then(result => {
      console.log('startup.epub read data: ', result);

      // Encrypt 
      const ciphertext = AES.encrypt(result, key);

      // Write encrypted file
      RNFetchBlob.fs.writeFile(RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DownloadDir + '/startup_enc.dat', ciphertext.toString(), 'base64')
      .then(() => {
        console.log('startup_enc.dat file wrtten');
        this.decrypt();
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('startup_enc.dat file writing error', error);
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('read error: ', err);
    });
  }
```

> I read the epub file in `base64` format. I encrypted the result with AES as `ciphertext` Then I wrote the `ciphertext.toString()` to `startup_enc.dat` file in `base64` encoding.

## Decryption

```
  decrypt() {

    //  DECRYPTION

    RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile(`${RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DownloadDir}/startup_enc.dat`, 'base64')
    .then(result => {
      console.log('startup_enc.dat data: ', result);

      // Decrypt
      const bytes = AES.decrypt(result, key);

      const plaintext = bytes.toString(enc.Base64);

      // Write decrypted file
      RNFetchBlob.fs.writeFile(RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DownloadDir + '/startup_dec.epub', plaintext, 'base64')
      .then(() => {
        console.log('startup_dec.epub file wrtten');
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('startup_dec.epub file writing error', error);
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('read error: ', err);
    });
  }
```

> Then I read the encrypted `startup_enc.dat` file in `base64` encoding. I decrypted the file and converted to `base64` format. Then I wrote the decrypted `plaintext` to `startup_dec.epub` again in `base64` encoding format.

The size of original epub file is `2.49 MB`, encrypted file is `3.11 MB` and the decrypted epub file is also `3.11 MB` unlike `2.49 MB`.

I am unable to find where the problem is, either in `encryption` or in `decryption` process. Can anybody help?

1. React-native-fetch-blob file streaming [DOCS](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/wiki/File-System-Access-API)
2. CryptoJS AES Encryption [DOCS](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js#aes-encryption)