# CryptoJS AES Encryption in React Native

Tags: encryption, react-native, aes, cryptojs, react-native-fetch-blob

How do I `encrypt` and `decrypt` an `epub/zip` file in react native? I am using react-native-fetch-blob for file streaming. I have also posted this question previously in detail with no result. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48238373/cryptojs-aes-decryption-not-giving-original-zip-epub-file-in-react-native) if you need. Also the link of [CryptoJS](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js#aes-encryption).

I was reading the epub/zip file in `base64` format which I think as equivalent of reading in binary format (or Am I wrong?). It works with single text file though.

Any Solutions? Thankyou.